# Delegates, Actions and Memory Allocations

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm currently working on a chunk of code that requires minimum memory allocations.

I've noticed if I use a method for a parameter the compiler changes the code and creates a new `Action`, but if I use an anonymous method the compiler creates a delegate block. I'm aware that the new `Action` allocates memory, but I'm not so sure about the delegate. Will delegates allocate memory when used?

My code:

```
bool workfinished = false;

void DoWork()
{
    MyMethod(CallBack1Work, ()=>{ workfinished = false;});
}

void MyMethod(Action callback1, Action callback2)
{
}

void CallBack1Work()
{
}
```

Compiler version:

```
bool workfinished = false;

void DoWork()
{
    MyMethod(new Action( CallBack1Work ), delegate{ workfinished = false;});
}

void MyMethod(Action callback1, Action callback2)
{
}

void CallBack1Work()
{
}
        
void DoWork_b01()
{
    workfinished = false;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://diditwith.net/2007/03/19/TheProblemWithDelegates.aspx), also [Will an empty delegate eat up memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703014/will-an-empty-delegate-eat-up-memory)

Comment: Can you change `MyMethod` to accept an `Action<ContainingClass>`? That will enable more caching options...

Comment: That is an option , I'm not too concerned about the amount of memory , I'm mostly concerned about generating garbage , like if the DoWork method was called a million times how much memory would be allocated. I'll have to run tests but its always good to hear it from an expert :)

Comment: I am also trying to minimize allocations. I have observed that an `Action<T>` is allocated in Debug but not in Release. (I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and running under .NET 4.5.2 on 64-bit Windows.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you explicit use `new SomeDelegate` or omit it, whether you use a lambda, the `delegate` keyword, or pass in a method group, or any possible solution you haven't shown.  In every single case a delegate object will be created.  The compiler can often infer that it should be there, so it doesn't force you to type it out; but the creation of that delegate is still happening no matter what.  (Well, technically you could pass in `null` and not allocate an object, but then you can't ever do any work, so I think it's safe to ignore that case.)

The only real difference in memory allocations between each of the options is that in the given anonymous method blocks you are closing over a variable (`workfinished`).  In order to create that closure the runtime will generate it's own type to store the state of the closure, create an instance of that type, and use that for the delegate, so all of the solutions using an anonymous method are creating one new object.  (Granted, it's small, so it's not going to be particularly expensive in most situations.)

Comment: It would be worth noting that there are scenarios where the compiler will cache and reuse a single delegate instance for a lambda - specifically when there is no captured context.

Comment: Thanks  , I was assuming the delegate keyword was actually creating a new delegate object but I wasn't 100% certain.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing that is confusing is that there is a method being created , so I wasn't sure if its a one time allocation or what. would look something like callback2_b01

Comment: @TimD: It would be one allocation per call. A small allocation, but present nonetheless.

Comment: I've proposed an alternative that hasn't been shown that *doesn't* create a delegate per call...

Answer (score 22):

If you use a lambda expression which doesn't capture anything, the compiler will generate a static field to cache it in. So use that, you can change the `Action` to an `Action<YourClass>` and call it with `this`. So:

```
class YourClass
{
    private bool workFinished;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyMethod(instance => instance.Callback1Work(),
                 instance => instance.workFinished = false);
    }

    private void MyMethod(Action<YourClass> callback1,
                          Action<YourClass> callback2)
    {
        // Do whatever you want here...
        callback1(this);
        // And here...
        callback2(this);
    }

    private void Callback1Work()
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

That will *only* create delegate instances the first time `DoWork` is called on *any* instance. The delegates will then be cached for all future calls on all instances.

Admittedly this is all an implementation detail. You could always make it clearer:

```
class YourClass
{
    private static readonly Action<YourClass> Callback1 = x => x.Callback1Work();
    private static readonly Action<YourClass> Callback2 = x => x.workFinished = false;

    private bool workFinished;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyMethod(Callback1, Callback2);
    }

    ... code as before ...
}
```

It's worth actually profiling and benchmarking the code before you go to any of these lengths though.

Another alternative would be to stick to `Action`, but create *instance* variables for the delegates - so as long as you called `DoWork` multiple times on the same instance, you'd be okay:

```
class YourClass
{
    private readonly Action foo;
    private readonly Action bar;

    private bool workFinished;

    public YourClass()
    {
        foo = Callback1Work;
        bar = () => workFinished = false;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyMethod(foo, bar);
    }

    public void MyMethod(Action callback1, Action callback2)
    {
        ...
    }

    private void Callback1Work()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```