# Where is the captured variables allocated in nested function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory, lambda

The nested function mentioned means it could be both lambda function and local function.

I am curious about where the captured variables are allocated.

For Example:

```
private Func<int> Test(int arg)
{
    var x = arg;
    return () => x;
}
```

The local variable `x` is captured by the lambda function returned.

Then where is this `x` allocated in memory? Is it on stack or heap memory?

If this `x` is on stack, any further call on `Test` could change the value of `x` and the behavior of the lambda function returned could be incorrectly modified.

But if it *is* dynamically allocated on heap memory, it would not be like a local variable any more.

Was it first allocated in stack and transferred to heap right on `Test` returns? (I guess not because it sounds like unnecessarily costing some resources, but how does it work to make it available to access this `x` after `Test` returns?)

Comment: Semantically, regardless of allocation details, each time `Test` is invoked there is a *different* (or "fresh") variable `x`. Thus, no two functions/closures returned (from different calls) can access the same `x` variable or otherwise directly interact.

Comment: `Func<T>` is a delegate. Not sure if related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357737/delegates-actions-and-memory-allocations

Comment: Everyone knows how it behaves but It is not exactly the question, which is, how come, where and how the local variables captured are allocated to make it behave so. @user2864740

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that `x` can't be allocated on the stack, since its lifetime exceeds the scope of the method where it was created.

Comment: It does not specify how local variables are captured so it is related to my question. @ChristianGollhardt

Comment: That is exactly what I wonder about. So, does it always causing a local variable to be allocated on the heap (even while it ought to be on the stack?) when it is captured by nested functions?

Comment: `I am curious about where the captured variables are allocated` Decompile the code and look. What the CLR and Jitter does to your variables are implementation details, it can decide on a whim and sometimes its not obvious. However taking your stack heap assumptions out, what is the actual question, "can x be modified ?"

Comment: once the outer function has returned, x cannot be modified externally for there is no reference to it from outsides, and it would work with no problem.@TheGeneral

Comment: @Alsein 1) If "everyone knew how it behaved", then it should be evident (to you) as to what part of the musing in the question that the comment was referring to; 2) If the comment was to be an answer, and in this case it clearly is not, it would be written as an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack vs heap isn't a very useful distinction here, but I can give you an idea of what happens. The compiler *re-writes* this code behind the scenes. It adds a class to the project which has an integer value as a member. Then both this function and the lambda function get a reference to the same instance of this new class.

At least, that's how this was handled the last time I read about it, which was admittedly some time ago now... but I doubt it's changed much. Welcome to programming, where everything you think you know is really a snapshot of how things were at some time in the past.

Comment: This looks to still be the true, according to dotMemory profiling. https://imgur.com/a/fTMbtNH

Comment: Thank you very much, so as long as a local variable is captured, it is not simply a local variable any more, is it? So are we supposed to avoid using local variable capturing in nested functions and to use argument passing instead, in order to avoid extra memory cost for the generated capturing context?

Comment: You're supposed to just not worry about it until a performance profiler tells you to worry about it. Code for clarity and maintainability, and only worry about a micro-optimization like that when your tooling tells you it's actually causing a problem.

Comment: But what if I want to make an algorithm and wish it to run as fast as possible?

Comment: Then you **definitely** want to be using a profiler, rather than guessing at what parts of the program are making things slow.

Comment: @Alsein There are several difference cases to consider for *potential* implementations, consider these different cases: 1) local variable captured, not modified, and assigned prior to creation of function (this would be akin to a `final` variable in Java closures); 2) local variable captured, not modified, but assigned after creation of function, but function is not invokable prior to being returned; 3) local variable captured, and possibly modified by function. The *relevant* bit in almost all cases is the semantic behavior - to see the actual implementation, view the decompiled IL.