# public event EventHandler SomeEvent = delegate { };

Tags: c#, events

I am kind of tired of having all this useless noise in my code:

```
private void RaiseSomeOtherEventIfItIsNotNull()
{
    if (this.SomeOtherEvent != null)
    {
        this.SomeOtherEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In 99.9% of the cases I don't care if someone attached to it or if it is null or not. Just raise the event! I really don't get it why the c# compiler makes me write all this noise.

So I though I could maybe declare an event like this:

```
public event EventHandler SomeOtherEvent = delegate { };
```

this would allow me to get rid of the useless null check and the useless Raise* Method. I could just always do:

```
this.SomeOtherEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Now when I compare the standard approach with "my" approach in Lutz Röder's Reflector I see some signigicant differences. The compiler has overriden `Add{}` and `Remove{}`there is an extra static instance of the anonymous delegate:

```
[CompilerGenerated] 
private static EventHandler CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1;
```

and there is this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void <.ctor>b__0(object, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs) cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ret 
}
```

Now my question: Do you seen any issues or disadvantages in decalring  events with a default initialization like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration

Comment: Yes, you are right, lets close this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've shown an extra *method*, but not the extra *class*. The extra method is fine, IMO - that's just representing the no-op handler. Not a problem.

An extra class is somewhat surprising, as is the idea that it's changing the add/remove behaviour... the compiler would *always* be creating add/remove methods for the event, as that's what makes it an event.

Personally I think this is fine - but an alternative would be to write extension methods, e.g.

```
public static void Raise<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T args)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, args);
    }
}

public static void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender,
                         EventArgs args)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, args);
    }
}
```

then just call

```
myEvent.Raise(this, args);
```

That will work for all `EventHandler` and `EventHandler<T>` events.

Comment: To be fair, I *mentioned* the extra class. Or is there another one I didn't see.

Comment: @bitbonk: Yes, you mentioned the extra class but didn't say anything about what it was. That's what I was surprised about - that there supposedly *is* an extra class. What's in it?

Comment: Ok it is not a extra class: `[CompilerGenerated]
private static EventHandler CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1;
` It's just an instance of the EventHandler delegate (wich is a class:) )

Comment: @bitbonk: No, that's not a class at all. It's a *field*... which is just used to cache the delegate so that only one is ever created, however many instances of the class you create.

Answer (score 1):

The convention used by microsoft is this :

Declare the event like this.

```
public event EventHandler<ChangedArgs> ItemChanged;
```

Then create a calling method

```
protected virtual void OnItemChanged(ChangedArgs args) 
{
     var handler = ItemChanged; 

     if (handler != null) 
         handler(this, args);
}
```

This also is ThreadSafe and whenever to raise the event, simply call OnItemChanged

Comment: Yes, that is the convention I am questioning.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no, since these are no-op handlers (since the IL generates a `nop` and a `ret` instruction). Assigning an empty handler is pretty much the same as having none at all, i.e. you do nothing about that event.

Comment: Well there is one difference: There will be one useless EventHandler.Invoke() wich might be slightly more expensive than a null check.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong (and if so, do tell me why, I'm curious too now), but maybe you need to declare the event delegate at class level?

```
public delegate void SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

?