# Using NavigationView in WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-islands

I want to use navigationView with xaml islands in a WPF project. I added the NavigationView to the project. There is no problem in terms of appearance. If I create a new page in code-behind I can switch between pages.

But when I want to open an attached page in my project, I encounter the following error.

***C# Code***

```
        private UIControls.Frame frame;
    private Media.FontFamily segoeFontFamily;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        segoeFontFamily = new Media.FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets");
    }

    private void Host_ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WindowsXamlHost host = (WindowsXamlHost)sender;

            if (host.Child is UIControls.NavigationView navigationView)
            {
                var configureItem = new UIControls.NavigationViewItem()
                {
                    Content = "Configure",
                    Icon = new UIControls.FontIcon()
                    {
                        FontFamily = segoeFontFamily,
                        Glyph = "\uE719",
                    }
                };

                var filterItem = new UIControls.NavigationViewItem()
                {
                    Content = "Filter",
                    Icon = new UIControls.FontIcon()
                    {
                        FontFamily = segoeFontFamily,
                        Glyph = "\uE8C7",
                    }
                };

                navigationView.MenuItems.Add(configureItem);
                navigationView.MenuItems.Add(filterItem);

                frame = new UIControls.Frame();
                navigationView.Content = frame;

                navigationView.SelectionChanged += NavigationView_SelectionChanged;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(UIControls.NavigationView sender, UIControls.NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.SelectedItem is UIControls.NavigationViewItem item)
            {
                switch (item.Content)
                {
                    case "Configure":
                        frame.Navigate(typeof(Configure));
                        break;

                    case "Filter":
                        frame.Navigate(typeof(CanBusFilterPage));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

***Xaml Code***

```
<xamlHost:WindowsXamlHost x:Name="Host"
                              InitialTypeName="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView"
                              ChildChanged="Host_ChildChanged"/>
```

***Error***

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a problem in you code at all. According to this article, it may be mixed configuration DDLs, you project settings, you .NET install or even an external .dll.

[Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot)

If this is definitely happening because of the WPF Window, make sure you have double-checked these leads, because this exception is caused by protected memory allocated from everywhere on you computer.

Comment: `frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName));` It gives the error in this part. If setting `frame.Content = new Page();` If I do it like this, there is no problem.

Comment: When Enable unmanaged code debugging was activated in the settings, the error changed as follows.  `Exception thrown at 0x7B3F9693 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in NavigationViewSample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Comment: Try to put Dispatcher.RunAsync around this line. Just like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922640/9192934.

Comment: Thanks @bondarenko, the error is gone but unfortunately it doesn't bring up the relevant page. What could cause the problem?

Comment: `_=Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() =>{frame.Navigate(typeof(Configure)); });` Sorry, problem not solved. I did it this way. It gives an error.  Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in NavigationViewSample.dll

Comment: I am not a Xamarin developer, and I can't be certain. In this way, try to post a different question, describe what you expected and what has been rendered instead. It could be some bug(s) in logic.

Comment: Do you have any information about the solution?

Comment: I do. See remarks section, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=net-5.0. 'A method that attempts to manipulate the UI from a thread that is not the main or UI thread'. It's recommended to read the exception message.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no RunAsync method as in the first link you mentioned. I guess that's why there is a problem with threads.

Comment: RunAsync works in a different thread pool. To ensure thread safety, you can use InvokeAsync.

Comment: I used the InvokeAsync method. I am getting the same error as the original post I received. The problem remains the same. Additionally, thank you for your time.

Comment: Then apparently this is related to the thread safety problem. You are welcome.

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate a little more. If I find a solution I will share it here.