# Raising Events in C#: performance and elegance

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, lambda

Being accustomed to VB.NET, I'm used to "just raise events". Sure, custom events differ, but with "regular" events - I don't need to check if the delegate is `Nothing` before raising.

With C#, I find myself repeating this pattern:

```
if (myHandler != null) 
{
    myHandler(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

I was thinking that the following pattern might prove more elegant:

1. myHandler is initialized with an empty lambda: `myHandler = (sender, e) => { };`
2. myHandler is expected never to be null, so raising would simply become: `myHandler(this, new EventArgs());`

Would this pattern be more or less performant than the previous one? 
Are there other significant considerations I should take into account?

Comment: See the answers to this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the **performance** difference between the two approaches *isn't big enough* to be relevant. If anything, I would argue that a null-check is *cheaper* than invoking a method through a delegate, even if it's a no-op.

When talking about **elegance**, it should be pointed out that the `RaiseEvent` keyword in VB.NET [is automatically expanded by the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188776.aspx#S3) to exact same construct that you have to write yourself in C#:

```
If (Not MyEvent Is Nothing) Then
  MyEvent.Invoke(New EventArgs())
End If
```

If you want to avoid repeating that construct throughout your code, you could encapsulate it in a couple of extension methods:

```
public static void RaiseEvent(this EventHandler source, object sender)
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        source.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public static void RaiseEvent<T>(this EventHandler<T> source, object sender, T eventArgs)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        source.Invoke(sender, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

That way you can simply say:

```
myEvent.RaiseEvent(this);
myOtherEvent.RaiseEvent(this, new SomeEventArgs());
```

which is semantically equivalent to the style used in VB.NET.

Answer (score 5):

It is something extra to happen in construction, but it won't be huge overhead. One thing to watch is that some serialization frameworks like `DataContractSerializer` (WCF) don't run constructors or field initializers, so it may not be non-null after all. Personally, if the majority of your events are `EventHandler`, I might be tempted to use an extension method:

```
public static void SafeInvoke(this EventHandler handler, object sender) {
    if (handler != null) handler(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

then:

```
SomeEvent.SafeInvoke(this);
```

although be frank, I rarely have a problem with simply using the null-check ;p

Another downside is that if you have enough events that this is an issue, you should probably be using `EventHandlerList` instead - and this approach won't work with `EventHandlerList`.

Answer (score 2):

Common practice is to use protected virtual methods OnEventName where you can check if event is null and raise it:

```
protected virtual void OnEventName(parameters)
{
    if (EventName != null)
        EventName(this, new EventNameEventArgs(parameters);
}
```

This allows you to have all event-raising code in one place (no null check duplication) and override it later if needed. So I don't see any benefit of adding one dummy event handler per event over having one null check per event.

BTW shorter way to add dummy handler is `myHandler = delegate {};`

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is significative difference between 1st and 2nd case provided, at least not so much to consider them. On *too frequent* use of delegates lack of `if (myHandler != null)` could, by the way, gane you some performance benefits. So if you're sure the handler is *never* `null`, get rid of that control and basically you done.