# Is it OK to always add an empty event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a downside to adding an anonymous empty delegate on event declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration)

The following pattern is quite common when using event handlers (in C#):

```
public event Action handler;
…
// some method:
if(handler != null) handler();
```

Are there any downsides of assigning an empty delegate to this event? This would save the `if !=null` condition everywhere, where the event is fired. Of course, this only applies, when the we cannot guarantee that the event is always assigned a proper delegate.

```
public event Action handler;
…
// in constructor:
handler += ()=>{};
…
// some method:
handler();
```

Sure, there's a slight performance hit, but it makes the code much cleaner. What's the best practice in such a case? Any technical disadvantages?

Comment: From my point of view isn't a good practice. Yes, you save a null check, but, a few months later, when inspecting the code for bugs or maintenance, the first example better demonstrates the purpose of the code.

Comment: It gets even worse - without protection, the `handler` may be set to null between checking for null and invoking it. You should copy the value of `handler` into a local variable and check _that_ for null.

Comment: Your first code is broken since you don't copy the value of `handler` into a local variable.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: why do I need to copy it into a local variable in the first example?

Comment: Because event subscription/unsubscription should be threadsafe. Your code can throw a `NullReferenceException` if the last handler unsubscribes between your check and raising the event.

Comment: @knittl if you are running this event from another thread the subscriber to the event may un-subscribe between checking for null and the event being run, which would then cause the handler to be null again. copying to a local variable will keep the state of the handler at that time and avoid un-registration errors.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: yeah, you are right. I see it now.

Comment: @knittl attempted example code in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an empty delegate in the constructor, you can wrap the handler in a function which first checks if the handler is null then calls it. The downside of this is if you have a lot of events, you will have a lot of functions that wrap each event.

```
private void HandlerWrapper()
{
    Action localHandler = handler;
    if (localHandler != null) handler();
}
```

Comment: same thread safety issues as the original code

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, I've never thought of doing that. The way i do my custom events is i make a OnCustomEventName taking parameters for the event and just do the check in there for null. and call OnCustomEventName from the code wherever i want the event triggered from.
Avoids any performance hits and keeps the operational code cleaner than a 2-line if check every time you want the event fired.

That being said this isn't answering the question about technical disadvantages but more of a best practice when firing events.

example code for threadsafe "On" function.

```
private void OnCustomEventName()
{
    DelegateName localhandler = CustomEventName;
    if (localhandler != null)
        localhandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found any big downsides to do this and generally I prefer it over checking for null. The only issue I cant think of is that it might lead to annoying steps in the code when debugging (i.e. 
having to step over the empty delegate whenever stepping into an event).

I think that performance isn't an issue - if application performance degenerates significantly by invoking events, the event should probably not have been there in the first place.