# Self-Testing delegates: avoid checking for null before invocation?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any smart way to avoid the verbosity of testing the nullity on an event before calling it in a generic way ? It looks obvious that if I call a delegate, I want it to be assigned.
(If I *Really* want/need to test its nullity I could eventually do it explicitly, but putting this test systematically is kind of tedious and verbose.)

```
public delegate void ResetTradesDelegate();
public ResetTradesDelegate ResetTradesEvents;

public void OnSessionRxAdmMessage(IVfxFixAppSession session, FixMessage msg)
{    
    if (ResetTradesEvent != null)  //<-- Is there "any" a way not to write this test explicitly for each delegate ?
       ResetTradesEvent();
}
```

Comment: I always copy it before testing (in case subscriptions change between check and call), however it's my understanding the test is necessary.

Comment: One approach some people take is to add a no-op handler for events in the object's constructor. It's not particularly elegant, but it does avoid the need for a null check.

Comment: I don't think this an issue of a `delegate`, but rather that of an `event` (which uses a MulticastDelegate?) and how they are implemented. Here if you assign a "dummy" delegate object (to the *non-event* member) then no check is required and it is *no different* than any other value that can be null ..

Comment: I agree with @dlev, but in my opinion it's "better" to check if something isn't null, before using it

Comment: I'd say just go for the no-op handler dlev mentioned. No matter how you write the check, it won't be 100% safe anyway.

Comment: Related: [Is there a downside to adding an anonymous empty delegate on event declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public event EventHandler NoDataEventHandler = delegate{};
```

Declaring an event in this way means it will never be null.  It will always, at a minimum, have a single no-op event handler hooked up.

In your case, probably

```
public event ResetTradesDelegate ResetTradesEvents = delegate{};
```

Firing an event is always going to have a race condition associated with it.  You're either going to risk trying to call a delegate when it's null, or calling a delegate after the event has been unhooked.  Eric Lippert wrote a pretty comprehensive post on this topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).  The technique above still suffers from the second type of race condition, so the event handlers need to be robust to being called after the event has been unhooked.

Comment: This works *until* you add an event and then remove it (so there are 0 wired events). Now the event delegate is `null` again .. because I have been affected by this issue before (a `null` where not-null was expected), I would recommend *against* using this approach ..

Comment: I have just written a test program with `public event EventHandler ValueChanged = delegate { };` that subscribes to the event `obj.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(obj_ValueChanged);`, changes a value (thus triggering the event handler), unsubscribes `obj.ValueChanged -= obj_ValueChanged;`, changes the value again (not triggering the event), but without any null reference exceptions.  Adding an event means there will be 2 event handlers hooked up.  Removing that event will put you back to 1 (the no-op delegate).  Are you 100% sure you weren't doing something else?

Answer (score 4):

```
static void CallIfNotNull(this Action action)
{
 if (action != null) action();
}
```

As an extension method, this is quite convenient to use.

Comment: This depends on the semantics of extension methods. If `this Action action` makes a copy of the value of the reference to the `Action`, then yes this works. Otherwise, you could still get a `NullReferenceException` if action was modified by another thread.

Comment: @MikeBantegui, parameters behave like locals. They are copies.

Comment: That's actually quite interesting. So modifying the values of a struct in an extension method does *not* do what you would expect it to.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, it is tedious to expand this over Func and different signatures .. also, for `event` if there is multi-threading at all, I believe the general advice is to acquire a lock while accessing the backing MulticastDelegate .. not sure how the implicit conversion to Action affects this.

Comment: @pst, this pattern is exactly what you should do in case of concurrent access. The parameter is a thread-safe snapshot of the event's value. This code is thread-safe. Locks are not required because delegates are immutable.

Comment: @usr Hmm, I could only convert an event delegate to Action via `new Action(eventDelegate)` (but not an implicit) but this *throws an exception* if the event delegate evaluates to null ..? In the case of `new Action(..)` it does appear a copy of the delegate list is made, as advertised.

Comment: If you want this function to work on arbitrary delegate types (and I recommend that you just use Action everywhere, even on events) you could make the method parameter of type `Delegate` and use Delegate.DynamicInvoke() to call it (at a certain perf hit).

Comment: What is meant by "..use Action everywhere, even on events"? Have a signature example?

Comment: `public event Action SomeName;`

Answer (score 2):

You can create your event-handler with an always-subscribed no-op event:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Event += (sender, e) => ();
    }

    public event EventHandler Event;

    protected virtual void OnEvent()
    {
        this.Event(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

However, this requires subscribing your event and will incur a performance penalty as the no-op delegate will still exist in the list of subscribed event handlers.

---

My preference here is to create a pair of extension methods to invoke any event handler, whilst performing a null-safe check:

```
public static void Raise(this EventHandler @event, object sender)
{
    if(@event != null)
    {
        @event.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public static void Raise<TEventArgs>(
    this EventHandler<TEventArgs> @event,
    object sender,
    TEventArgs args)
    where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    if(@event != null)
    {
        @event.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

This can then be easily invoked anywhere in your library to safely raise the event:

```
this.ResetTradesEvent.Raise(this);
```

It's purely syntactic sugar; you're still doing the check on the delegate. It is however, a nice re-usable way to wrap up this smelly part of the C# language.

Comment: Not only does the no-op handler get invoked, but the event will also now always refer to a materialized delegate object (vs. `null`). I believe using `null` was, at least at conception, a design decision to minimize unneeded objects for un-wired events. In any case, still a +1 .. also I think it would be cleaner to just rename `event` then use the keyword-breaker syntax.

Comment: "Keyword-breaker syntax"; I like that phrase. Would you have a more preferable argument name? I thought a little on this when adding it to my own libraries, but couldn't find anything I personally found clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the null conditional operator keeps the test but is less verbose so works for me. I don't imagine it resolves the race condition that others have mentioned.

```
ResetTradesEvent?.Invoke();
```

This is suggested automatically in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Call(this Action action)
{
    var safeAction = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref action, null, null);
    if (safeAction != null)
        safeAction();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation