# initialized delegates in class diagram

Tags: c#, delegates, class-diagram

I use Visual Studio 2015, and I have created a class diagram to have an overview of my most-used classes and their members.

I have a delegate defined in a class named **UserMessage**:

```
public delegate void ProcessUserMessage(UserMessage message);
```

I use this delegate in an other class:

```
public UserMessage.ProcessUserMessage ProcessUserMessage;
```

So far no problems.

Because I hate testing the callback for null every time, I hook up a no-op event handler at initialization, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460145):

```
public UserMessage.ProcessUserMessage ProcessUserMessage = delegate { };
```

But when I do that, and re-open the class diagram, it fails to load, saying:

> Code could not be found for one or more shapes in class diagram 'ClassDiagram1.cd'. Do you want to attempt to automatically repair the class diagram?

The auto-repair doesn't work of course ;-(

Even when I place this initiatlization in the class' constructor, instead of at the declaration, the same error appears.

I fail to understand what's wrong. Any clues?

---

**Update:**
I created a blank project with just the failing code:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public UserMessage.ProcessUserMessageDelegate ProcessUserMessage = delegate { };
}

public class UserMessage
{
    public delegate void ProcessUserMessageDelegate(string foo);
}
```

The strange thing is that the class diagram for MainWindow loads fine, but for UserMessage it fails. But I am not changing anythign for UserMessage.

It loads OK if I change class MainWindow to:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public UserMessage.ProcessUserMessageDelegate ProcessUserMessage;
}
```

Comment: Try again in a new project with the minimal elements.  It's not clear that you have identified the correct source of the error.

Comment: I tried that, @HenkHolterman, but it's still the same.
The funny thing is that it correctly shows the main class diagram, but it fails to load the **UserMessage** class diagram. But I made changes in the main class, not in the UserMessage class

Comment: Then post the full source code (not the diagram), mark (comment out) what causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution...

The anonymous no-op delegate must conform to the delegate definition, so all I had to add was add the argument (`(string foo)` in this example):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public UserMessage.ProcessUserMessageDelegate ProcessUserMessage = delegate (string foo){ };
}

public class UserMessage
{
    public delegate void ProcessUserMessageDelegate(string foo);
}
```