# Should event firing in C# always be protected by a null check?

Tags: c#, events, null-check

This situation seem very interesting to me.

In C# you need to check if there is any listener to the event in a class before firing it.

Assuming event structure of C# is a non-standart(Meaning Microsoft did it) implementation of Observer observable pattern for ease of use.

Why didn't they implement this inside that structure? Is there solid reasons or documentation for this choice.

**Is it a necessity do null checking, or am I wrong in my assumption for event structures needing null checks under all circumstances.**

This is a more of a curiosity question looking for an answer to this implementation choice by microsoft. Which I hope will lead to further understanding of delegate and event keyword inner workings.

Comment: Well things like user interface controls usually have lots of events but very few observers. Why do we need to give these unused events some special non-null value?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration that is also a good way to avoid checking for null.

Comment: That calling an event doesn't implicitly check for null was a dumb mistake on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Events does not need some special value. Event is a keyword which a compiler creates a list to hold delegates to call. I am wondering why didn't microsoft implemented further improvements on the concept? And asking if there is documentation or explpanation for this choice.

Comment: No you shouldn't if you are going to see what happens when the 'null' is being called

Comment: @CodesInChoas Yeah that's what I am suspecting. Also this the reason I wanted to ask this question. Because your knowledge and my knowledge maybe limited on the subject :D

Comment: There's a reply to this question in [a blog by Eric Gunnerson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/19/why-do-i-need-a-null-test-before-i-invoke-a-delegate.aspx) Basically it seems to say that they thought about changing it, but it could break existing code. Anyway, it seems @CodesInChaos is correct. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you. Very enlightening. Can you please make an answer with the link and some summary/explanation. I think that is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: +1, I never actually thought about this problem. I'm adding this to my 'List of little things where VB.NET feels better than C#'. (I love C#.) You can raise whatever you want in VB.NET without a check.

Comment: @GSerg nice I didn't know about that. So It means VB.NET's event keyword should create different IL codes than C# event keyword. I will  try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reply to this question in [a blog by Eric Gunnerson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/19/why-do-i-need-a-null-test-before-i-invoke-a-delegate.aspx).

Basically it seems to say that Microsoft thought about changing it, but it would break existing code.

In other words, it *was* a mistake in the original design for events, but it's too late to fix it.

Comment: I think that blog post raises even more important questions about race condition from if null check as a thread can check for a delegate then enter the if block and get an interrupt. While another thread unregisters all delegates. Which makes me believe it is totaly unsafe.

Comment: @AliAkdurak Yes, I always make a copy of the handler and check the copy for null and call the copy rather than the original, for this very reason.

Comment: Funny, the LINQ2SQL designer does not make a copy of the handler before checking: `if ((this.PropertyChanging != null)) {this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);}`

Comment: @GSerg If it's some user interface control then it's fine because most user interface controls are not re-entrant and can only be used on the main thread. You have no expectation of them working in a concurrent context.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must do the `null` check.

Calling a delegate that is `null` results in a `NullReferenceException`.

You might be tempted to intialize all delegates with a non-null, empty event handler. However, that would be far worse than testing for `null`, in terms of CPU usage, memory usage, and lines of code.

Comment: I definitely agree with your answer. It is basically checking a function pointer if it is pointing something to. But when we use as a event there is a list of delegates initialized behind event keyword ? What do you think about this. Would it be able to implement such list management behind the code that is created by event keyword.

Comment: @AliAkdurak for more information, read all the answers and comments on them to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration

Comment: I will check the linked question and answer.

Comment: This link you have given provides detailed implementation benchmarks and methods for such null checking. A very good reference IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default event listener, thus avoiding the null check

```
public Action<object, EventArgs> SomeEvent = (o, e) => { };
```

in that way, you can call SomeEvent without checking for null, since it contains a default (empty implementation) listener. Please note that it might hurt performance.

Comment: You can, but IMO you should not. See [Is there a downside to adding an anonymous empty delegate on event declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration) for a longer discussion.