# What is the point of assigning an empty delegate to an event?

Tags: c#, events

I have just come across this code in a book I'm working through:

```
public event EventHandler<ProjectEventArgs> ProjectUpdated = delegate { };
```

Is setting a delegate here merely to ensure `ProjectUpdated` is never null, and this avoid the standard null check before firing the event?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why.

Comment: See also [Is there a downside to adding an anonymous empty delegate on event declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you are to raise an event, you have to check for null values, meaning, no event handlers attached. With this approach, you can skip this check, because the event will always have an empty handler.